# Nested eager loading in where clause in Laravel

Tags: orm, eloquent, laravel-5.1, eager-loading

I want to know is there anyway to write query like this in Laravel using Eloquent. I mean can i do eager loading in where clause. I am stuck here from last day and i really want to do like this. So suggestions needed.

```
        $notifications = Notification::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)
            ->where('is_try', '!=', Config::get('constants.NOTIFICATION_AGAINST_JOB_TURN_DOWN'))
            ->where('is_try', '!=', Config::get('constants.NOTIFICATION_AGAINST_JOB_EXPIRED'))
            ->where(function($query) {
                $query->where(function($query) {
                    $query->where('message', '!=', 'job_post')
                        ->with(['suggestion' => function ($query) {
                            $query->with(['job' => function ($query) {
                                $query->with('company');
                            }]);
                        }]);
                    })
                    ->orWhere(function($query){
                        $query->where('message','job_post')
                        ->with(['job' => function ($query) {
                            $query->with('company');
                        }]);
                });
            })
            ->orderBy('notifications.created_at','desc')
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

as per my knowledge, you can load the the relationship like this `$query->load('company');` instead of `$query->with('company');`

also you can load multiple/nested relationship like this.

```
Notification::with([
                    'rel'=>function($q){ $q->where()... //can add up where, orderby etc clauses like this},
                     rel.profile, 
                     rel.profile.images, 
                     rel.profile.images.location

                  ])->wehre()....
```

also you can do this,

```
$course_orignal     =   Courses::find($course_id);

$course_orignal->load('quizzes','quizzes.questions', 'chapters','chapters.quizzes.questions','chapters.lessons','chapters.lessons.quizzes','chapters.lessons.quizzes.questions');
```